# Increase the size of dock's active application symbol

Tags: macos, dock

Is there any way I can increase the size of this dot (?) that signifies an application is open?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, this isn't possible in macOS -- it is fixed at that size.

You can remove them completely from displaying in the Dock by going to System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar and unchecking: **Show indicators for open applications.**